# CrashLoopBackOff for kube-scheduler Due to Missing Service Token

Tags: kubernetes, kube-scheduler

I have a problem with my Kubernetes cluster where my kube-scheduler pod is stuck in the 'CrashLoopBackOff' state and I am unable to rectify it. the logs are complaining of a missing service token:

```
kubectl logs kube-scheduler-master -n kube-system
I1011 09:01:04.309289       1 serving.go:319] Generated self-signed cert in-memory
W1011 09:01:20.579733       1 authentication.go:387] failed to read in-cluster kubeconfig for delegated authentication: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
W1011 09:01:20.579889       1 authentication.go:249] No authentication-kubeconfig provided in order to lookup client-ca-file in configmap/extension-apiserver-authentication in kube-system, so client certificate authentication won't work.
W1011 09:01:20.579917       1 authentication.go:252] No authentication-kubeconfig provided in order to lookup requestheader-client-ca-file in configmap/extension-apiserver-authentication in kube-system, so request-header client certificate authentication won't work.
W1011 09:01:20.579990       1 authorization.go:177] failed to read in-cluster kubeconfig for delegated authorization: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
W1011 09:01:20.580040       1 authorization.go:146] No authorization-kubeconfig provided, so SubjectAccessReview of authorization tokens won't work.
invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided
```

Can anyone please explain what `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` is, where is it supposed to be stored (is the path on the host or within the container) and how do I go about regenerating it?

I'm running version 1.15.4 across all of my nodes which were set up using `kubeadm`. I have *stupidly* upgrade the cluster since this error first started (I read that it could possibly be a bug in the version I was using). I was previously using version 1.14.*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated; everything runs on this cluster and I feel like my arms have been cut off with out it.

Thanks in advance,

Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, as the pod is `kube-scheduler`, the `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` the logs are referring to are is mounted from `/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf` on the master node.

For whatever reason, this was a completely empty file in my cluster. I regenerated it by following the instructions for kube-scheduler on [Kubernetes the hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md):

I ran the following in the `/etc/kubernetes/pki` directory (where the original CAs remained):

```
{

cat > kube-scheduler-csr.json <<EOF
{
  "CN": "system:kube-scheduler",
  "key": {
    "algo": "rsa",
    "size": 2048
  },
  "names": [
    {
      "C": "US",
      "L": "Portland",
      "O": "system:kube-scheduler",
      "OU": "Kubernetes The Hard Way",
      "ST": "Oregon"
    }
  ]
}
EOF

cfssl gencert \
  -ca=ca.pem \
  -ca-key=ca-key.pem \
  -config=ca-config.json \
  -profile=kubernetes \
  kube-scheduler-csr.json | cfssljson -bare kube-scheduler

}
```

which generates `kube-scheduler-key.pem` and `kube-scheduler.pem`.

Next, I needed to generate the new config file using the instructions [here](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/05-kubernetes-configuration-files.md).

I ran:

```
{
  kubectl config set-cluster kubernetes-the-hard-way \
    --certificate-authority=ca.pem \
    --embed-certs=true \
    --server=https://127.0.0.1:6443 \
    --kubeconfig=kube-scheduler.kubeconfig

  kubectl config set-credentials system:kube-scheduler \
    --client-certificate=kube-scheduler.pem \
    --client-key=kube-scheduler-key.pem \
    --embed-certs=true \
    --kubeconfig=kube-scheduler.kubeconfig

  kubectl config set-context default \
    --cluster=kubernetes-the-hard-way \
    --user=system:kube-scheduler \
    --kubeconfig=kube-scheduler.kubeconfig

  kubectl config use-context default --kubeconfig=kube-scheduler.kubeconfig
}
```

which generates `kube-scheduler.kubeconfig` which I renamed and moved to `/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf`.

It was then just a case of reading the logs from the pod (`kubectl  logs kube-scheduler-xxxxxxx -n kube-system`) which will complain about various things missing from the configuration file.

These were the 'clusters' and 'contexts' blocks of the YAML which I copied from one of the other configuration files in the same directory (after verifying that they were all identical).

After copying those into `scheduler.conf` the errors stopped and everything kicked back into life.

Answer (score 7):

By default `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` is mounted in every pod and contains the authentication token to access your Kubernetes API server.

You can disable mounting it by specifying `automountServiceAccountToken: false` in your deployment configuration. Some tools like `terraform` with Kubernetes provisioner disable mounting the token by default as well. On `terraform` this can be reenabled by adding `automount_service_account_token = true` to the deployment spec.

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks for explaining what it is. I'm assuming ```kube-scheduler``` will need access to the Kubernetes API server so I think I might need to regenerate it as opposed to remove it from the pod.

Comment: yes, depending on your setup it could be something with a service account or (as mentioned) with an IaC tool default. to list the token, you can run `kubectl get secrets` and then `kubectl delete secret xxx` to remove it, it will be autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Kubernetes v13.
I fixed it with the following commands.

An empty scheduler.conf file causes a `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`.

So, we remove it.

```
$ rm /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
```

And regenerate scheduler.conf.

```
$ kubeadm init phase kubeconfig scheduler --apiserver-advertise-address <YOUR_IP>
```